# Allow iframe in custom meta box

Tags: metabox, post-meta, escaping, iframe

I've created a custom meta box called 'Location Map' and want to provide a functionality to the client to simply copy paste the location's google map's iframe embed code so that it directly appears on the front-end. The value just doesn't store. Below is the code to save the meta box.

```
/* Save the meta box's post metadata. */
function kk_save_location_map( $post_id, $post ) {

    /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
    if ( !isset( $_POST['location_map_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['location_map_nonce'], basename( __FILE__ ) ) )
        return $post_id;

    /* Get the post type object. */
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

    /* Check if the current user has permission to edit the post. */
    if ( !current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['location-map'] ) ? ( $_POST['location-map'] ) : '' );

    /* Get the meta key. */
    $meta_key = 'location-map';

    /* Get the meta value of the custom field key. */
    $meta_value = esc_textarea(get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true ));

    /* If a new meta value was added and there was no previous value, add it. */
    if ( $new_meta_value && '' == $meta_value )
        add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value, true );

    /* If the new meta value does not match the old value, update it. */
    elseif ( $new_meta_value && $new_meta_value != $meta_value )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value );

    /* If there is no new meta value but an old value exists, delete it. */
    elseif ( '' == $new_meta_value && $meta_value )
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
}
```

I've tried with `esc_html`, `esc_attr`, `esc_textarea`, `wp_kses` and what not without success.

Comment: Which hook are you using to attach that function?

Comment: That would be `add_action( 'save_post', 'kk_save_location_map', 10, 2 );`

Comment: Let me also add that I've added some other regular CMBs too and they work fine. The same code has been used for this one. The problem is with it not saving iframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your code and it works:

I changed the `wp_verify_nonce` function, because that wasn't working for me. I added an action instead of what it had. Now, for this to work, you have to create a nonce field with a code like this, of course that you can change the names if you want.

```
//this goes in the function that generates the metabox    
wp_nonce_field( 'location_map_nonce_action', 'location_map_nonce' );
```

And this is the finall code of the function that save the values.

```
function kk_save_location_map( $post_id, $post ) {



    /* Verify the nonce before proceeding. */
    if ( !isset( $_POST['location_map_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['location_map_nonce'], 'location_map_nonce_action' ) ){
            return $post_id;
     }

    /* Get the post type object. */
    $post_type = get_post_type_object( $post->post_type );

    /* Check if the current user has permission to edit the post. */
    if ( !current_user_can( $post_type->cap->edit_post, $post_id ) ){

        return $post_id;
    }

    /* Get the posted data and sanitize it for use as an HTML class. */
    $new_meta_value = ( isset( $_POST['location-map'] ) ? ( $_POST['location-map'] ) : '' );

    /* Get the meta key. */
    $meta_key = 'location-map';

    /* Get the meta value of the custom field key. */
    $meta_value = esc_textarea(get_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, true ));

    /* If a new meta value was added and there was no previous value, add it. */
    if ( $new_meta_value && '' == $meta_value ){

        add_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value, true );
    }
    /* If the new meta value does not match the old value, update it. */
    elseif ( $new_meta_value && $new_meta_value != $meta_value ){

        update_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $new_meta_value );
    }
    /* If there is no new meta value but an old value exists, delete it. */
    elseif ( '' == $new_meta_value && $meta_value ){

        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value );
    }   

}

add_action( 'save_post', 'kk_save_location_map', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: That didn't work either. On the contrary the meta box stopped saving the value even once which it did before. I've updated the code on my staging server. Is there a way I can give you its credentials?

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is the iframe tag, you could make a filter and just have them leave out the iframe tag.

```
<?php 

function my_custom_filter ( $filter_output ) {
    $meta_value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'location-map', true);
    $filter_output = str_replace( '{{ location-map }}', '<iframe ' . $meta_value['location-map'] . '></iframe>', $filter_output );

    return $filter_output;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, after messing around with my entire `functions.php`, I figured out where the actual problem was. The function for displaying the meta box was incorrect

**BEFORE**

```
function kk_custom_meta_box2( $object, $box ) { ?>

<?php wp_nonce_field( 'location_map_nonce_action', 'location_map_nonce' ); ?>

<p>
    <label for="location-map"><?php _e( "Enter the location's map using Google map's embed function<br>", 'ac' ); ?></label>
    <textarea class="widefat" type="text" name="location-map" id="location-map">
        <?php echo esc_html(get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'location-map', true )); ?>
    </textarea>
</p>
<?php }
```

**AFTER**

```
function kk_custom_meta_box2( $object, $box ) { ?>

<?php wp_nonce_field( 'location_map_nonce_action', 'location_map_nonce' ); ?>

<p>
    <label for="location-map"><?php _e( "Enter the location's map using Google map's embed function<br>", 'ac' ); ?></label>
    <textarea class="widefat" type="text" name="location-map" id="location-map">
        <?php echo get_post_meta( $object->ID, 'location-map', true ); ?>
    </textarea>
</p>
<?php }
```

I simply had to remove `esc_html` from its value so that the update function doesn't mess with it.

Comment: Hi, this is a different problem. Also, try to escape the textarea using the `esc_textarea` function. You never know who is gonna use the plugin.

Comment: You jammed that right into my head. Security should always be considered first.